# Which voting method is the most fair?

Tags: statistics, voting-theory

I have heard of

- Plurality
- Borda Count
- Instant Runoff
- Sequential Pairwise

voting methods, where it mathematically can be proved which is the most fair and in which situations.

From my understanding Sequential Pairwise does not seam fair at all, as the order in which you compare have a influence on the outcome. With Instant Runoff I would assume is not suited when there are few voting options and most of them have few votes.

**Question**

Does anyone know which is the most fair and when each of the methods should be used?

Comment: This seems to be a question of opinion, unless you're fishing for a reference to [Arrow's impossibility theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem) which suitably interpreted says that there is _no_ voting method that is not in some arguable way inferior to another voting method.

Comment: Most important point: Define fair

Comment: The fairness of a voting system comes from how well its rules are understood and executed. A highly sophisticated system may theoretically be fair but if no one understands how it works, then it's useless.

Comment: Donald Saari has done nice work in support of the Borda Count as 'mathematically' the best. But the question of 'best' really can't be disconnected from the question of what one wants and what one can expect from a voting system.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Arrow's theorem only applies to ranked-choice systems; Arrow says that ratings systems aren't covered by it.  Gibbard's theorem, however, does show that all systems are subject to some degree of strategic voting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to mention the following voting system: let each voter rank all candidates in order of preference (a total preorder will do, i.e., voters are allowed to rank two candidates equally).  Now tabulate, for each pair $(i,j)$ of candidates, the number of voters who placed $i$ before $j$ minus the number who placed $j$ before $i$.  This gives an antisymmetric matrix which can be considered as the payoff matrix of a symmetric zero-sum game.  By the von Neumann minimax theorem, this game has an optimal mixed strategy, and moreover, it is unique in general (barring generalized "ties"; for example, it can be made almost surely unique by adding a voter with infinitesimal weight who votes for a random permutation in the order of the candidates, or by some other kind of tie-breaking strategy).  Now choose the candidate according to the probabilities given by this optimal strategy: this candidate is considered elected.  (Note that this is not deterministic: there is a random choice at the end; however, if there is a Condorcet winner, which is exactly the same thing as an optimal pure strategy in the game, then there will be no random choice.)

This voting system is optimal exactly in the sense that the optimal strategy for the game is optimal.  That is, if I choose the election's winner according to the voting system described above, and you choose the election winner according to some other voting system, then the expected number of voters happier with my choice (i.e., having placed my choice higher in their ballot) is at least as great as the expected number of voters happier with yours, since the difference between them is exactly the outcome of the game and I am playing the optimal strategy for that game.  So in this sense, this voting system is the best when it comes to making the most electors happy.

(I don't know if this voting system has a name.  I like to call it the Condorcet-von-Neumann or Condorcet-Nash voting system, because it is a Condorcet voting system obtained by using the Nash equilibrium for the obvious game.  But the idea is so obvious that it has probably been described countless times in various different ways.  I just don't have a reference.  **Edit:** From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454148/what-is-the-strategy-proofness-of-maximal-lottery), I learn that the (or at least "a") standard name for this voting system is, in fact, "[maximal lotteries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_lotteries)"; and as I expected, it has been rediscovered a number of times.)

Of course whether it is politically acceptable to have an element of randomness in an election is another problem, and since that one is non-mathematical, I won't comment any further.

Comment: What properties would this have if you voted for parties instead. Specifically, a party gets a number of representatives proportional to its probability in the mixed equilibrium.

Comment: Oh, and even more politically unacceptable is how *complicated* it is. Like, if you were a dictator and you want a body to accurately represent the people, this method would be find. If you are forming a democratic country, most people would not accept this since they couldn't understand it (unfortunately).

Comment: Also, does this system gravitate towards a two party system?

Comment: These questions were also asked in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453021/properties-of-this-game-theory-based-voting-system).

Comment: @PyRulez: This system describes how to elect *one* person, not how to elect an assembly or anything, so the question about parties is hard to answer.  Concerning complexity, there are electoral systems being used (or having been used) in the world which are way more complicated, like in the German Bundestag (mixed local-proportional with overspill) or for French regional elections (two-tiered proportional with two election rounds).  People generally don't understand them, but they get the general idea.  I think the random element is much more problematic.

Comment: @joriki Whoops sorry I deleted that one. I'm gonna to make another though.

Comment: @PyRulez: Gee, why did you delete it? It was such an interesting and relevant question!

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: I live in Germany and am active in party politics, and I slightly disagree. I agree that people in general don't understand the entire election system, but they do feel that it's something that people other than mathematicians, e.g. TV commentators and more educated voters, can understand, at least with a bit of effort, and can thus monitor and correct. I think that with this sort of system (which I find very original and very interesting), reservations would be stronger, not just because of the random element but because it feels more like something only mathematicians understand.

Comment: (I speak partly from experience, since one of my hobby horses is to try to establish theoretically more preferable but more complex voting systems in the German Green party. :-)

Comment: @joriki Oh sorry. I found out the actual name, and wanted to write it better, but then fell asleep. I'll do that now.

Comment: @joriki Okay, here it is again: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454148/what-is-the-strategy-proofness-of-maximal-lottery

Comment: @PyRulez: Ah, nice, you re-asked precisely the part of the question for which I'd already written an answer :-)